# Check that Html is using with Node-webkit or not?

Tags: javascript, html, licensing, node-webkit, nw.js

I want the Html file only run with Node-webkit because of license purpose, **not** allow to run on **any** other browser (Chrome, Safari, Firefox...)

Can we check by the Html file that it's running with Node-webkit or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for some of the node-webkit specific stuff, such as if `process.versions` has a `node-webkit` property:

```
if (typeof process !== "undefined" && process.versions['node-webkit']) {
    console.log('You are using node-webkit!');    
}
```